# JavaScript - How do you make a function that can only run once at a time?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this simple JavaScript function:

```
var exclusiveFunction = function(){
    for(index in firstArray)
    {
        for(secondIndex in firstArray[index])
        {
            // do stuff to firstArray[index][secondIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

My question: there's a chance this code gets called multiple times before one call can finish the whole function. What I would like:

```
 if(exclusiveFunction.workingAtTheMoment)
 {
      exclusiveFunction.stopFunction();
      exclusiveFunction();  
 }
```

Basically, check if the function is running, and if it is, halt it (and every instance of it running), and start it again. Is this possible?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded.

Comment: if function is running or not can be resolved with flags, stop function - impossible. "run once at time" - very unclear - once in loop ? once per some time?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScripts are single threaded and callbacks should be used to provide asynchronous behaviour. Your function doesn't have any callbacks. Because of that it's working in the way you want..

Comment: Callbacks don't create any concurrency.

Comment: According to my knowledge, callbacks are used to create time-division multiplexing in single threaded event loop. This produces concurrency... Where am I wrong?

Comment: Callbacks are just a way pass an action instead of a value. It has nothing to do with time or concurrency. You can't have concurrency with a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use varible to keep track of function excetuion

```
var isFunRunning =0;

var exclusiveFunction = function(){
if(isFunRunning==0)
{    
    isFunRunning =1;    
    for(index in firstArray)
        {
            for(secondIndex in firstArray[index])
            {
                // do stuff to firstArray[index][secondIndex]
            }
        }
    isFunRunning=0;
}
else {  

//code to keep count of function triggered in between

 }
        }
```

or Go through this 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/

OR__________________________________________________________________-

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
var count =0;

 var exclusiveFunction = function(){

  if(isFunRunning==0)
    {    
        isFunRunning =1;    
        for(index in firstArray)
            {
                for(secondIndex in firstArray[index])
                {
                    // do stuff to firstArray[index][secondIndex]
                }
            }
        isFunRunning=0;
    }
    else {  

        callbacks.add( exclusiveFunction );
        count ++;

     }
            }
```

then fire the callback

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a chance of creating parallel functions (maybe events or async; I'm not interested about this idea), but you can stop function like that:

```
window.someCounter = 0;
function doSomethingUntilOtherCall(){
    var myID = ++window.someCounter;
    while (myID === window.someCounter){
        // do something
    }
}
```